# Guardar texto con formato asignado

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hola estoy creando una app de procesamiento de texto, el problema que tengo es que al guardar el archivo pierde el formato asignado, estuve buscando pero no encuentro alguna forma para conservar ese formato, alguien sabe como lograr esto?

Aqui por ejemplo asigno letras negritas a la seleccion:

```
 public static void Negritas(){
        startSelection= Archivo.getSelectionStart();
        endSelection=  Archivo.getSelectionEnd();
        Log.d("Seleccion", "Inicia: "+startSelection+" Fin: "+endSelection);
        String selectedText = Archivo.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, 
        endSelection);
        Log.d("SubString", ": "+selectedText);
        SpannableStringBuilder texto= new SpannableStringBuilder(selectedText);
        SpannableStringBuilder complete=new SpannableStringBuilder(Archivo.getText());
        StyleSpan letraEnNegrita= new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);
        texto.setSpan(letraEnNegrita, 0, selectedText.length(), 
        Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        complete.replace(startSelection,endSelection,texto);
        Archivo.setText("");
        Archivo.setText(complete);
    }
```

Se aplica correctamente, después guardo mi archivo:

```
grd.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            String name=NmbArchivo.getText().toString();
            if(name!=null) {
                Intent create = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
                create.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
              //create.setType("text/plain");
                create.setType("application/msword");
                create.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, name);
                startActivityForResult(create, 300);

            }
        });


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        String treeUri=null;
        if (treeUri != null ) {
            uriSD = Uri.parse(treeUri);
            Log.d("ResultFinal: ", " --" + treeUri + "--" + uriSD);
            content = getContentResolver();
            content.takePersistableUriPermission(uriSD, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
        if (requestCode == 300 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            OutputStream fileOutupStream = null;
            Contenido = Archivo.getText().toString();
            byte[] dts = new byte[Contenido.length()];
            for (int w = 0; w < dts.length; w++) {
                byte gr = Contenido.getBytes()[w];
                dts[w] = (gr);
            }
            try {
                fileOutupStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(data.getData());
                fileOutupStream.write(dts, 0, dts.length);
                bandV = false;
                visivilidad();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Archivo guardado correctamente",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", " " + e);
            }
        }
    }
```

El problema es que al abrir el archivo ya no muestra las letras en negritas por ejemplo.
Alguna sugerencia?

Saludos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como guardar un archivo de texto manteniendo su formato?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/599611/como-guardar-un-archivo-de-texto-manteniendo-su-formato)